# Can't Connect to MYSQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried connecting to mysql via my registered server on dreamhost, and via localhost. Neither one seems to work. I know I'm giving the proper data for user and such, but all I get is a dead connection.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04...

**edit**

Ok, sorry for the lack of description. I have added my ip to the Dreamhost control panel. My code resembles the following:

```
 define('SERVER', 'mysql.hostname.com');
        define('USERNAME', 'xxxxx');
        define('PASSWORD', 'xxxxx');

        $connection = mysql_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die("error, cannot connect to mysql.");
```

when I do a var_dump() on the variable, all I get is a simple

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Seriously, how is one supposed to figure out what is wrong, from the description here? Have you considered calling support? Does mysql -hhostname connect?

Comment: Honestly, you need to provide MANY more details... Is this even a programming question? I can't tell. MySQL could be for anything.

Comment: read this page for a start  http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/qt/php_in_mysql.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure this strictly belongs here, and I'd really like more information about, say, the specific PHP code you're using to log in, but here are a few gotchas with Dreamhost, just in case they happen to match your particular issue:

1. The mysql server is *not* `localhost` or your web server's domain. Instead, it's usually `mysql.mydomain.com`. Check your specific MySQL settings in the Dreamhost control panel.
2. If you try to connect from another computer, you will be rejected unless that IP address has specifically been added in the MySQL section of Dreamhost's control panel. I noted you tried via `localhost`, but note that, even if you're trying the right server as per suggestion #1, you'll still get bum results from your personal computer unless the IP is whitelisted.

Comment: In fact, there is an example on Dreamhost http://wiki.dreamhost.com/MySQL_and_PHP

Answer (score 1):

For the one on dreamhost, unless you specify that connections can be accepted from your local ip, it will not work. Read up on Mysql Access Control [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html)

As for localhost, it should connect, but you need to provide more information on what your setup is i.e. whether you are connecting through -hhostname or just connecting through a local socket. Also what do you mean by "dead connection".

Comment: Sorry, but I know nothing about socket programming. How do I check?